# Running UF from a 200 amp meter base 1250 feet. Want to end up with 100 amp service

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am installing a new electrical service on my property.  Power company wants $20,000 to bury wire from road to house location.  I need a better alternative.  Considering having service drop on front of property and then coming from their meter to my proposed house location.  It is around 1250 feet.  I will direct bury myself.  I am also considering stepping voltage up at road to reduce wire size and stepping down at homesite.

What size wire with and without Transformers and if with transformers, what KVA should I get to handle the load.  Many years ago was an electrician so not completely unfamiliar with this process.  Just wondering what the economical way to do this is as 25KVA transformers are pretty expensive as is wire.

thanks in advance

Comment: I think it's just a matter of economics: Price of larger cable vs price of step up/step down transformers.   Perhaps (I dk, i'm not an expert here), but maybe your PoCo could provide higher voltage at the service, like 600v, then step it down at the home with your own transformer.   AGAIN, I DK for sure.  Hopefully one of the experts here will weigh in.

Comment: Who's your power company? It might be easier to get a 480V irrigation service and run it out to the house, then step it down there...

Comment: Direct burial is cheap, once. Trenches are expensive. Conduit is cheap. Conduit provides extra protection for the wires within that direct burial cable does not offer. The second time you have to dig the trench, direct burial looks very expensive. What's the objection to an overhead line on poles? Those usually cost considerably less, and you can run a reasonable length of underground from the last pole if you don't want overhead wires at the house end.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion's. HOA demands all underground.  I will find out about what kind of transformer they can leave as that could save a bunch

Comment: @creationsoft -- we can usually figure out what's available for transformer options from your POCO's rulebooks (unless you have one of those annoying POCOs that doesn't publish their service and metering rules, that is)

Comment: I have called the engineer on my poco project and he is offering no help on design although he did say he would look into a 480 meter So i dont have to step up from 240 to 480

Comment: Wow... You've got enough land that the house is 1/4 mile from the road, yet there's still an HOA to deal with? Yikes!

Answer (score 2):

### You're very much best off with a transformer-based approach here

For such an extremely long run, there is absolutely no contest that you'll want to run it at something well north of 240V.  (Trying to do it at 240V while keeping voltage drop under 3% at 80A would require 3 4/0 Al triplexes *in parallel*, which is far more expensive than transformers would be.)

Given your run length, you have two options.  Either you can take service at single phase 240/480V if your utility is willing to play ball, then run that out to a transformer at the house, or you can take a standard 120/240V service and step it up for the run, again stepping it back down when you reach the house.  The former case requires heavier-duty service equipment and slightly heavier wire, but keeps transformer losses down, while the latter  lets you use thinner wire and standard 240V service equipment at the cost of an additional transformation.

### Taking the extra volts

For the 240/480V option, the cheapest solution is to have a fused safety switch as your service entrance device -- the Siemens HF362NR is inexpensive and readily available, and will work just fine when paired with 600V Class R fuses of the appropriate amperage rating.  This then feeds a trio of 3/0 Al conductors (two hots and a grounding conductor) in a 2" or 2½" PVC conduit.

Note that you'll likely need a pair of grounding rods at the service entrance location, and your utility may also require a *cold sequence* setup, i.e. switch-fuse-meter vs. meter-switch-fuse, for your 480V service.

Once your run reaches the house, you'll step it down to 120/240V with a standard 25kVA 480V/240V single phase transformer in a NEMA 3R enclosure, parked on a pad adjacent to the house, with the secondary neutral bonded to the transformer case and to a grounding electrode that's part of the pad.  This transformer then provides two hots and a neutral to a main panel configured as service equipment, and everything from there on is standard house wiring.  (This configuration is permitted by NEC 250.30(A)(1) Exception 2, if you're wondering how it works out in the Code.)

### Stepping it up yourself

Alternately, if you have to, or would rather, take a standard 240V service, you can take your pick of service entrance equipment, then use it to reverse feed a 25kVA, 600V/240V transformer located at the service entrance.   The run then becomes a 1/0 triplex (hot, neutral, ground) in 2" or 2½" PVC between the service-entrance transformer and the house-transformer.

You'll still need grounding electrodes at the service entrance, neutral bonding on one side of the 600V run (cheaper than ground detectors), and a grounding/bonding wire (which has to be a wire, since it's serving as both EGC and GEC in this circumstance as per the Exception to 250.121) in the run from the service entrance hardware to the transformer, though.  You'll also need to fit a 600V fuse block and corresponding fuse in the inter-transformer circuit; while NEC 240.21(C)(1) lets you get away with not protecting the inter-transformer wiring with secondary fusing, you still need a primary fuse for the house-transformer to comply with NEC 450.3.  Note that this fuse block can be mounted in either transformer's enclosure, though, as the 240V service disconnect provides it with a supply-side disconnecting means.

Once you get to the house, the installation plays out the same as above, save for using a 600V/240V transformer instead of the 480V/240V one.  Either way, you'll get 100A at the house with 3% drop at 80A, for far less money than simply throwing fat aluminum at the problem will cost.